# Correctly writing a javascript regex to split a stirng

Tags: javascript, regex

This is an example of the input:

```
var input="0-test-different-0_0:11,0-test-different-0_1:54,0-test-different-1_0:19,0-test-different-1_1:8,0-test-same-2_0:20,0-test-same-2_1:20,0-test-different-3_0:19,0-test-different-3_1:16,0-test-different-4_0:18,0-test-different-4_1:17,0-test-different-5_0:20,0-test-different-5_1:11,0-test-different-6_0:20,0-test-different-6_1:12,0-test-same-7_0:20,0-test-same-7_1:16,0-test-different-8_0:17,0-test-different-8_1:11,0-test-same-9_0:19,0-test-same-9_1:17,01-trial-same-10_0:19,01-trial-same-10_1:23,02-trial-different-11_0:22,02-trial-different-11_1:10,03-trial-different-12_0:20,03-trial-different-12_1:12,04-trial-same-13_0:18,04-trial-same-13_1:14,05-trial-same-14_0:17,05-trial-same-14_1:19,06-trial-different-15_0:21,06-trial-different-15_1:10,07-trial-same-16_0:20,07-trial-same-16_1:17,08-trial-different-17_0:20,08-trial-different-17_1:8,09-trial-same-18_0:20,09-trial-same-18_1:10,10-trial-different-19_0:21,10-trial-different-19_1:10,11-trial-same-20_0:19,11-trial-same-20_1:12,12-trial-same-21_0:19,12-trial-same-21_1:16,13-trial-different-22_0:19,13-trial-different-22_1:14,14-trial-different-23_0:22,14-trial-different-23_1:13,15-trial-same-24_0:19,15-trial-same-24_1:12,16-trial-same-25_0:18,16-trial-same-25_1:10,17-trial-different-26_0:20,17-trial-different-26_1:30,18-trial-different-27_0:21,18-trial-different-27_1:20,19-trial-same-28_0:17,19-trial-same-28_1:15,20-trial-different-29_0:17,20-trial-different-29_1:12,21-trial-different-30_0:18,21-trial-different-30_1:11,22-trial-different-31_0:16,22-trial-different-31_1:13,23-trial-same-32_0:19,23-trial-same-32_1:13,24-trial-different-33_0:19,24-trial-different-33_1:11,25-trial-same-34_0:20,25-trial-same-34_1:17,26-trial-same-35_0:22,26-trial-same-35_1:20,27-trial-same-36_0:20,27-trial-same-36_1:14,28-trial-same-37_0:22,28-trial-same-37_1:11,29-trial-different-38_0:19,29-trial-different-38_1:15,30-trial-same-39_0:19,30-trial-same-39_1:14,31-trial-different-40_0:18,31-trial-different-40_1:10,32-trial-different-41_0:18,32-trial-different-41_1:12-0-test-different-0_0:8,0-test-different-0_1:54,0-test-different-1_0:21,0-test-different-1_1:11,0-test-same-2_0:24,0-test-same-2_1:20,0-test-different-3_0:13,0-test-different-3_1:18,0-test-different-4_0:20,0-test-different-4_1:20,0-test-different-5_0:19,0-test-different-5_1:10,0-test-different-6_0:18,0-test-different-6_1:13,0-test-same-7_0:16,0-test-same-7_1:16,0-test-different-8_0:15,0-test-different-8_1:10,0-test-same-9_0:22,0-test-same-9_1:15,01-trial-same-10_0:20,01-trial-same-10_1:23,02-trial-different-11_0:24,02-trial-different-11_1:14,03-trial-different-12_0:18,03-trial-different-12_1:14,04-trial-same-13_0:18,04-trial-same-13_1:12,05-trial-same-14_0:23,05-trial-same-14_1:21,06-trial-different-15_0:21,06-trial-different-15_1:12,07-trial-same-16_0:19,07-trial-same-16_1:16,08-trial-different-17_0:22,08-trial-different-17_1:8,09-trial-same-18_0:21,09-trial-same-18_1:7,10-trial-different-19_0:16,10-trial-different-19_1:10,11-trial-same-20_0:21,11-trial-same-20_1:10,12-trial-same-21_0:18,12-trial-same-21_1:20,13-trial-different-22_0:19,13-trial-different-22_1:13,14-trial-different-23_0:17,14-trial-different-23_1:9,15-trial-same-24_0:19,15-trial-same-24_1:11,16-trial-same-25_0:23,16-trial-same-25_1:11,17-trial-different-26_0:21,17-trial-different-26_1:27,18-trial-different-27_0:20,18-trial-different-27_1:22,19-trial-same-28_0:19,19-trial-same-28_1:19,20-trial-different-29_0:21,20-trial-different-29_1:10,21-trial-different-30_0:19,21-trial-different-30_1:11,22-trial-different-31_0:20,22-trial-different-31_1:10,23-trial-same-32_0:21,23-trial-same-32_1:10,24-trial-different-33_0:19,24-trial-different-33_1:14,25-trial-same-34_0:16,25-trial-same-34_1:16,26-trial-same-35_0:22,26-trial-same-35_1:22,27-trial-same-36_0:23,27-trial-same-36_1:18,28-trial-same-37_0:19,28-trial-same-37_1:12,29-trial-different-38_0:21,29-trial-different-38_1:13,30-trial-same-39_0:22,30-trial-same-39_1:13,31-trial-different-40_0:21,31-trial-different-40_1:11,32-trial-different-41_0:19,32-trial-different-41_1:11";
```

At string index 2015 there is a - which actually separates this string in two.

It is different from all the other dashes in that it is the ONLY one preceeded by a colon (:) and then 1 to N numbers before there is a dash.

The way I've been finding it is by using this procedure:

```
var searchingColon = true;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
   if ((searchingColon) && (input.charAt(i) == ':')){
       searchingColon = false;
   }
   else if (!searchingColon){
      if (input.charAt(i) == "-"){
         console.log("Found at " + i);
         return;
      }
      if (isNaN(parseInt(input.charAt(i), 10))) {
         searchingColon = true;
      }    
   }
}
```

However it takes a while and I thought a regular expression would be better.

So I've tried this:

```
regex = "/:[0-9]+-/"
var res = input.search(regex)
console.log(res)
```

But res is -1, which mean it hasn't found anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the quotes. Regular expressions in JavaScript are enclosed by forward slashes, not quotes.

```
regex = /:[0-9]+-/;
var res = input.search(regex)
console.log(res)
```

However, you can create a regex surround by quotes if you use the Regex constructor.

```
var regex2 = new RegExp(':[0-9]+-');
```

I usually prefer the first method, because you have to escape the `\` and use `\\` if you use the string variation.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I'm able I'll accept your answer

Comment: If your regex isn't correct, I can try to help fix that too. Let me know.